# Interpreting the Granger Causality Test

Tags: interpretation, causality, statsmodels, granger-causality

I am trying to go through an online time series analysis tutorial and they use the `Granger Causality Test` to see if there is some benefit to jointly model two time series using a VAR model.

I ran the causality test on my data using the built-in test using `statsmodels` python package and I set the `maxlags` parameter to `3`. So, I obtain the following output:

```
Granger Causality
number of lags (no zero) 1
ssr based F test:         F=19.4064 , p=0.0000  , df_denom=2875, 
df_num=1
ssr based chi2 test:   chi2=19.4266 , p=0.0000  , df=1
likelihood ratio test: chi2=19.3614 , p=0.0000  , df=1
parameter F test:         F=19.4064 , p=0.0000  , df_denom=2875, 
df_num=1

Granger Causality
number of lags (no zero) 2
ssr based F test:         F=3.2541  , p=0.0388  , df_denom=2872, 
df_num=2
ssr based chi2 test:   chi2=6.5196  , p=0.0384  , df=2
likelihood ratio test: chi2=6.5122  , p=0.0385  , df=2
parameter F test:         F=3.2541  , p=0.0388  , df_denom=2872, 
df_num=2

Granger Causality
number of lags (no zero) 3
ssr based F test:         F=0.3887  , p=0.7611  , df_denom=2869, 
df_num=3
ssr based chi2 test:   chi2=1.1690  , p=0.7605  , df=3
likelihood ratio test: chi2=1.1687  , p=0.7605  , df=3
parameter F test:         F=0.3887  , p=0.7611  , df_denom=2869, 
df_num=3
```

So the p-values increase as the number of lags increase. So, is this telling me that if I lag one series wrt to the other by 1, I can derive the maximum benefit and lagging the series further would make the dependence disappear? Does this test tell me anything more than suggesting that forecasts on these series may benefit from multivariate modeling?

Another thing I want to ask is there any notion of causality involved or is it more like correlation? For example, which series is the causal effect and which one is the effect?